# Duda con phpmailer

Tags: php, javascript, phpmailer

Estoy enviando un correo en PHP utilizando la librería php mailer pero el problema está en que quiero que mientras se envié el correo el botón diga **loading** y después que diga se ha enviado exitosamente su correo revise la bandeja de entrada

Código PHP:

```
//send mails

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Helo = "smtp.gmail.com"; // nombre del dominio de primer nivel
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //servidor donde se enviara el email
$mail->Port = "465";
$mail->Username = "a@a.com"; //cuenta que enviara los correos
$mail->Password = "123456"; //contraseña de la cuenta
$mail->From = "a@a.com"; // correo de quien lo envia
$mail->FromName = 'titulo'; //nombre o titulo referente al destinatario
$mail->Subject = 'sub'; //titulo que aparece despues de quien lo envia
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->AddAddress(a@a.com); //para quien va
$mail->Body = "ok"; //cuerpo del mensaje
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

if(!$mail->Send()){
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
   /* aqui el mensaje que se a enviado exitosamente */
}
```

Código javascript:

```
var url = "a.php";
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: $("#3as3dsad22s1").serialize(),
  success: function(data) {
    $("#asd2a2sd23333asd").html(data);
  }
});
return false;
```

Les agradezco la ayuda

Comment: Y qué hiciste desde la vista (html)? Para poder ayudarte a hacer lo que necesitás.

Comment: es un formulario que envio por ajax me retorna informacion sin recargar pero quiero que me retorne que el boton por ejemplo de enviar correo cuando le den click diga espere y cuando se envie el correo diga correo enviado exitosamente

Comment: Gracias, podrás agregar ese fragmento en donde hacés la petición por ajax? Eso va a servir como para generar una respuesta.

Comment: claro que si: 

var url = "a.php"; 
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#3as3dsad22s1").serialize(), 
        success: function(data)
        {
        $("#asd2a2sd23333asd").html(data); 
        }
        });
         
        return false;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tan solo podrías usar la función `beforeSend()` del ajax para agregarle el texto de `loading` al botón y luego, una vez que termine de ejecutarse, mostrar el mensaje ya se de éxito o no.

#### HTML

```
<button id="send-mail">Enviar mail</button>
<div id="status-mail"></div>
```

#### Javascript

```
$('#send-mail').on('click', function() {
  var url = "a.php";
  var self = $(this);
  var textButton = self.text();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: $("#miform").serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() {
      // cambio  el texto del botón antes de enviarlo por ajax
      self.text('loading...');
    },
    success: function(data) {
      // vuelvo a poner el botón el mismo texto que tenía
      self.text(textButton);

      // agrego el texto que devuelve el PHP
      $('#status-mail').text(data.msg);
    }
  });
});
```

#### PHP

```
//send mails

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
$mail->Helo = "smtp.gmail.com"; // nombre del dominio de primer nivel
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; //servidor donde se enviara el email
$mail->Port = "465";
$mail->Username = "a@a.com"; //cuenta que enviara los correos
$mail->Password = "123456"; //contraseña de la cuenta
$mail->From = "a@a.com"; // correo de quien lo envia
$mail->FromName = 'titulo'; //nombre o titulo referente al destinatario
$mail->Subject = 'sub'; //titulo que aparece despues de quien lo envia
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->AddAddress(a@a.com); //para quien va
$mail->Body = "ok"; //cuerpo del mensaje
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

if(!$mail->Send()){
    echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo));
} else {
    /* aqui el mensaje que se a enviado exitosamente */
    echo json_encode(array('msg' => 'El mail se envió exitosamente.'));
}
```

Comment: Gracias es lo que necesitaba solo que me gustaría que el botón se deshabilitara para que el usuario espere mientras la función se realiza

Answer (score 0):

ojala te ayude. Creo que sería algo así:

Supongamos que tu botón esta:

```
<button id="btnEnviarMail">Enviar Mail</button>
```

Entonces en tu método:

```
$('#btnEnviarMail').click( function() { 
$('#btnEnviarMail').text('Enviando correo...')
var url = "a.php";
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: $("#3as3dsad22s1").serialize(),
  success: function(data) {
    $('#btnEnviarMail').text('Correo enviado!')
  },
 error: function(data) {
 $('#btnEnviarMail').text('Error al enviar')
}
});
return false;
})
```